# Instalar aplicación . NET para todos los Usuarios de Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, estoy intentando publicar mi aplicación para generar un instalador, lo cual se genera sin mayor problema pero cuando lo ejecuto en la PC solo se instala en el Usuario activo de Windows, mi pregunta es como hacer para que el programa aparezca en todos los usuarios.
Notas. Utilizo Windows 10.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, agrega lo que tratas de realizar en tu pregunta, que sistema operativo usas, etc, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: El puesto de trabajo tiene Windows 10

Comment: Con que estas haciendo tu instalador?

Comment: Publicándolo directamente desde Visual Studio

Comment: Tal vez estés buscando una herramienta como las sugeridas en [este sitio](https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/4-tools-to-create-windows-installer-packages/)

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo, justo lo que buscaba, Saludos!